# PAN Gesture is crashing while taking the location of touch in view in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I just do a sample to check the pan gesture.

The pan gesture is detecting and working fine.

But whenever i give a secondPoint in the pan gesture like `CGPoint secondPoint = [sender locationOfTouch:1 inView:self.imageView];` it is crashing.

The console is giving the message

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[UIPanGestureRecognizer locationOfTouch:inView:]: index (1) beyond bounds (1).'
```

When I use `panGestureRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;`
     panGestureRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches =1; still it is crashing.

When I use `panGestureRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 2;`
     `panGestureRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 2;` 
then it is not entering into the

```
- (void)panGestureHandler:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender method.
```

Can anyone please guide me where im going wrong.

Thanks in advance.Hoping for your help.

I tried in this way.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panGestureHandler:)];
     panGestureRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 2;
     [self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];

}
- (void)panGestureHandler:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if ([sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan )
    {
        CGPoint firstPoint = [sender locationOfTouch:0 inView:self.imageView];
        CGPoint secondPoint = [sender locationOfTouch:1 inView:self.imageView];
    }
    else if ([sender state] ==UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded ) 
    {
    }

}
```

Comment: The problem with maximum and minimum number of touches=2 is solved when i tested it in device.Thanks all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You provided a `maximumNumberOfTouches`, but no `minimumNumberOfTouches`. I.e., the gesture can be recognized after the *first* touch. In this case, no second touch may exist, and your index `1` (referring the second element) exceeds the array bounds.

Comment: whenever i give it like this  panGestureRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 2;
     panGestureRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches =2;
it is not entering into the - (void)panGestureHandler:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender{} method.

Comment: @mitthias can you please guide me

Comment: @user923370: Can you confirm that the gesture recognizer does not recognize a gesture with two fingers? The `[minimum|maximum]NumberOfTouches` gives you the number of fingers for the touch, not the states during the gesture.

Answer (score 6):

I too came across this error despite the max and min number of touches being set.  I'm subclassing my gesture recognizer and figure it has something to do with that.  I got around it by simply checking `numberOfTouches` before referencing it:

```
if ([gestureRecognizer numberOfTouches] > 0) {
    CGPoint point = [gestureRecognizer locationOfTouch:0 inView:self.superview.window];
}
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 2):

When the max/min touches are set, they determines whether it is a valid gesture to begin sending action but they are not the criteria for ending it. For example, if you set the max/min to 2. If a two-finger-touch is  detected, the handler starts receiving the action. Leaving one finger will not end the gesture. The handler still receive action with change-state and one touch. In the end, the handler receives 0 touch and end-state.

Comment: It should be comment i think.

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that on this line:

```
    CGPoint secondPoint = [sender locationOfTouch:1 inView:self.imageView];
```

index "1" is out of `locationOfTouches` bounds. So, as stated above, you need to make sure you set `minimumNumberOfTouches`

Additionally, you will want to enabled user interaction on the image view in order for it to respond to gesture recognizers.

```
[self.imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

Comment: @NSPostWhenldle i have set the minimum number of touches.but still it is crashing.http://pastebin.com/VjVYpNm0 this is my code.can you please have a look at it and guide me where im going  wrong.

Comment: @user923370 What does the new crash say?

Comment: @NSPostWhenldle the same error.       Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[UIPanGestureRecognizer locationOfTouch:inView:]: index (1) beyond bounds (1).'

Comment: @user923370 Does changing the index to "0" help at all, and try setting the gestures delegate to self.